How can we enable scrolling up the page upon clicking a button in HTML simply?
The issue pertains to the length of the code used for scrolling up the page upon button click.
<div class="back-to-top">
      <a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
    </div>
    
  <hr>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('back-to-top').addEventListener('click', () => {
     window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  });
</script>

I found the current code for scrolling up the page upon button click to be somewhat lengthy. Any suggestions for a more concise implementation?

You can even achive this without using any JavaScript like this. But make sure there isn't any element with the id top in your page. You can also simply set href="#" in your back to top button to make sure you won't run into any problems.


html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 4px;
}

#example-content {
  height: 1000px;
}
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="example-content">
      Top of the page
    </p>
    <p>Bottom of the page</p>

    <a id="back-to-top" href="#top">Back to Top</a>
  </body>
</html>



